# What does " <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>" mean and how is it used?

Tags: xslt, linq-to-xml, xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

I'm working on (my first) DITA project using Oxygen, and invoking FOP to generate PDF output. Trying to figure out what everything along the chain does, where the chain is: document -> element -> class -> class template definition in .xsl -> attribute settings in attr.xsl

I'm doing fine with all except the class template definition, which invariably seems to involve the line: `<xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>`

Where is that template stored and how is it configured?

(I found a lot of questions that show the correct syntax for invoking this template, or others, but not what doing this actually means.)

Comment: The expression calls the template with name commonattributes

Comment: "*Where is that template stored ...*" It's stored either in the same stylesheet that calls it or in another stylesheet that your stylesheet includes or imports. -- "*... and how is it configured?*" We don't see it, so we have no way of telling.

Comment: Thank you! From this I finally figured out what to search for. Mischief managed.

Comment: @M.Rivera: If you have found a solution to you own problem, let SO participate by posting an answer to you own question.

Comment: I can't explain it well enough to compose an answer! But the answer below is great.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the DITA Open Toolkit (OT). In version 2.2.4 of the OT this named template is in the following file:

DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/xsl/fo/commons.xsl

This template applies other templates to some common attributes like @id. I doubt that you will need to "configure" it, and it does not have any parameters. Here it is:

```
<!-- Process common attributes -->
<xsl:template name="commonattributes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-startprop ')] |
                               *[contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-endprop ')]" mode="flag-attributes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT templates can be matched against the input document when written with a `@match` attribute or called procedurally when written with a `@name` attribute.

You've encountered a procedural call of a template named `commonattributes`, which would be defined directly within your XSLT file or indirectly via `xsl:include` or `xsl:import`.

Without seeing the definition of `commonattributes` we can easily guess that its purpose is to consolidate the definition of a common set of attributes to a single location so that they be centrally managed and applied via `xsl:call-template` to multiple elements generated by your XSLT.  This is a common pattern in XSLT.